# TSQL: How to cast varchar as numeric when some entries are text

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have a table with two relevant columns: A primary key and an amount.  The 'amount' represents money and is one of two things: Either a numeric value (e.g., 47.50) or the word 'unliquidated'.

I want to use aggregate functions on this data set.  The following works just fine when the criteria doesn't return any records with the 'unliquidated' amount:

```
select count(primary_key), sum(cast(amount as numeric)
from (table)
where (criteria)
```

However, if the (criteria) returns any records that are 'unliquidated', then it throws the following error:

> "Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Error converting data type
>   varchar to numeric.

I would like my query to (a) count 'Unliquidated' records in the 'count' function, and (b) treat 'Unliquidated' as a 'zero' for purposes of the sum function.  As such, simply altering the criteria to exclude the unliquidateds doesn't work.

Comment: this is a textbook example of why you do not store multiple pieces of data in a single column.  Don't store a status value in the same column as an amount! it just makes everything harder.

Comment: I have no control over the data structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although y state the the only non-numeric string in the column is 'unliquidated', I don't necessarily believe that.  In any case, this should be safe:

```
select count(primary_key),
       sum(case when isnumeric(amount) = 1 then cast(amount as numeric) end)
from table
where (criteria);
```

`ISNUMERIC` returns 1 when the string is a currency amount or written in scientific notation. In these cases the cast would fail, but it sounds like that won't happen here.

Note that you have to put the condition in a `case` statement or you might still get an error.

In SQL Server 2012+, you can also use `try_convert()`.

And, I would be inclined to use `money` instead of `numeric` as the destination data type.

Comment: I like the `CASE` approach.  I do not like using `money` data type though.

Comment: ISNUMERIC returns 1(true) for values like `'1234e6'` . A safer way of doing this would `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'`

Comment: @M.Ali The OP explicitly defines the only non numeric value.

Comment: After reading the question more carefully, I'm not allowed to change my vote until the question is edited! Sorry.

Comment: Edited the answer to make it clearer that ISNUMERIC is safe to use here. Have an upvote! :-)

Comment: The money datatype is a hold over from long ago. More importantly you didn't declare a scale or precision for your numeric. That means you get an int. Change the cast to have a scale and precision and this will will work just fine with the usual caveats about ISNUMERIC.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NullIF`

```
select count(primary_key), sum(cast(nullif(amount,'unliquidated') as numeric))
from (table)
where (criteria)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(primary_key), SUM(CASE ISNUMERIC(amount) WHEN 1 THEN cast(amount as numeric) END) AS Amount
FROM   (table)
WHERE  (criteria)
```